# Law of Demeter issues with complex class design

Tags: java, design, design-patterns

I've posted questions pertaining to this issue before, but they've all tackled different aspects of the problem (Just so you know that I'm not reposting the same question to get more answers).

So, in a nutshell, here is my problem: I have a `Timeline` class, which has-a `Content` interface member variable. The Timeline manages WHEN the content gets activated. There is also a `Trigger` class, which gets a reference to the `Timeline` class and call the `Timeline`'s `play()` methods at certain times (like when the user hits spacebar). To organize the `Triggers` and the `Timeline` together, they're bound together in a class called `Cue` (which is the only class the rest of the program cares about).

This leads me to a design problem, since this `Cue` class is used so often throughout my code, it would be a pain to change it later.

Because of the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_Of_Demeter), should I not make getters and setters for the `timeline` and `triggers` member variables, and instead copy many of their functions into `Cue` (and just call the functions of the member variables in turn). That way, other classes won't know the inner workings of it?

Answer (score 2):

> Because of the LoD, should I not make getters and setters for the timeline and triggers member variables, and instead copy many of their functions into Cue (and just call the functions of the member variables in turn). That way, other classes won't know the inner workings of it?

I would resolve this in one of three ways, depending on the Timeline / Trigger operations that must be performed in the application code.

If the application code needs to be able to call most methods of Timeline and Trigger, then adding delegations to Cue is pointless.  Every addition to Timeline or Trigger will require a corresponding change in Cue, and you will have made the code worse, not better.

If the application code needs to call many methods, but some methods must not be called on objects encapsulated in a Cue, then I might create new interfaces for Timeline and Trigger that expose only those methods, and have Cue publish those interfaces instead of the full interfaces.

If the application code needs perform only a few operations on Timeline and Trigger, or only a few special sequences of operations, then I would add methods do Cue and hide the contained Timeline and Trigger.